# populate 'url' field in $resourse service for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and I create small ui application to visualize data. I read that it is better to leave controller clean and put all server calls into separate services. So I decided to create such service using custom factory and $resource.

As I understand I could populate some fields in $resource. So I have written such code

```
app.factory("serviceCallService", ['$resource', function($resource){
 return $resource('http://:url', null, {
  getProfiles: {method:'GET',headers :{ //some headers}}
 });
}])
```

in my controller I used something like this

serviceCallService.getProfiles({'url':$scope.currentUrl})

but in console I see that $resource fails with error because it tries use such url `http://:url`
May be someone could suggest me some solution

P.S.
Currently I don't have access to my working machine. As soon as I get access I will add some screenshots and console logs

Comment: I tried it on my application, and I was also unable to use `'http://:url'` but I could use `':url'` and then have the whole path in the url variable ($scope.currentUrl)

Comment: @klskl, in case I use simply ':url' then $resource build URL using my service URL  + $scope.currentUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem where if you use '/' (slashes) in parameters, the request will fail (bad request). But there is also a workaround that you can find [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1388)

From git workaround:

```
// In angular-resource.js and method encodeUriSegment
  function encodeUriSegment(val) {
  return encodeUriQuery(val, true).
  replace(/%26/gi, '&').
  replace(/%3D/gi, '=').
  replace(/%2B/gi, '+'). 
  replace(/%2F/gi, '/'); // <--- Add this line
}
```

I tried this solution, and it worked.

This is my query function:

```
   this.queryItem = function (){
   var url = "http://serverURL/items";

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var items = Deviation.query({ url: url },function() {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

in $resource factory:

```
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
      url: ":url"
    },
```

as you can see I override the $resource url with another url (that uses the parameter only) inside the `query` function.

Answer (score 0):

Proposal:

```
app.factory("serviceCallService", ['$resource', function($resource){
   getProfiles: function(url){
     return $resource(url, null, {
     getProfiles: {method:'GET',headers :{ //some headers}}
   }
 });
}])
```

call this by using `serviceCallService.getProfiles($scope.currentUrl)`